# tinymce dijit.editor

Tags: plugins, editor, dojo

I have been using tinyMCE over dojo dijit.editor because tinyMCE wins out on functionality. Though I've just come across this: http://phphtmledit.com/dojo/ShowEditor.php?gclid=CPizxJzR3qQCFQpBbgodFidd9A
which, if I'm reading it correctly, claims to be a dojo editor but has all the functionality of tinyMCE.

So my question: are there more dijit.editor plugins out there? So far I've found these: http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/editor/plugins 
http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/_editor/plugins

In particular, is there an image inserter plugin for dijit.editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an image uploading / inserting plugin - [dojox.editor.plugins.UploadImage](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/HEAD/dojox.editor.plugins.UploadImage)

Comment: Are you able to get it to work? I tried it last night but it just presented the OS file browser and then threw a bunch of errors

Answer (score 0):

The demo behind your link looks like a demo of the http://cutesoft.net/ WYSIWYG editor. (Found the link in the HTML source) You can always mail cutesoft and ask them if they build their editor on top of dojo...

As far as I know all the editor stuff in dojo is documented behind the links you already found and you can of course always write your own plugin.